# To find repetitions of a particular digit in a number

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

For example my input is `12451`. I need to get the number of times that `1` is repeated in the number.

Comment: Perhaps remove all the 1's from the input and compare the lengths?

Comment: So what would be the answer for this example?

Comment: In `awk` you can use for example:  `awk '{print gsub(/1/,"")}' <<<'12451'`. Or for example: `awk '{print gsub(/1/,"")}' <<<$'12451\n123123123'`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ echo 12451 | grep -o . | grep -c 1
2
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
$ echo 12451 | gawk -v num=1 'BEGIN { FS = "" } {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == $num) count++ } END {print $count}'
2
```

With POSIX awk as [suggested in this
comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665774/to-find-repetitions-of-a-particular-digit-in-a-number#comment1252880_665774):

```
$ echo 12451 | awk '{print gsub(/1/,"")}'
2
```

Comment: Instead of adding that superfluous clumpsy `gawk` solution you should have explained the relevant solutions, I think.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ string=12451
$ echo ${#string//[^1]}
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data arrives on standard input (e.g. piped from `echo`):

```bsh
LC_ALL=C tr -d -c '1' | LC_ALL=C wc -c
```

This deletes any character that is not `1` and then counts the remaining characters.

Assuming the data is kept in a shell variable, `value`, in e.g. `bash`:

```bsh
ones=${value//[\!1]/}; echo "${#ones}"
```

This does virtually the same thing as the first command.  It deletes all the non-`1` characters from the value `$value`, assigns the resulting string to the new variable `ones`, and outputs the length of that string.

Comment: Beware that with several implementations of `tr` including GNU `tr`, that would return 1 on the output of `echo fräulein` if in a locale using the GB18030 charset for instance. As the encoding of `ä` is 0x81 0x30 0x8a 0x31 in that charset (0x31 being also the encoding of `1`)

Comment: The `bash` one will either count the `1` characters or the 0x31 bytes depending on whether `$value` can be fully decoded as text or not. Would find 0 in `fräulein` in those Chinese locales using GB18030, but would find one in `fräulein$'\200'`. ksh93 (where that syntax is from) and zsh are OK. In zsh, you don't need the temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method with grep and line count using wc:

```
grep -o '1' <<< 12451 | wc -l
```